# I am unable to handle SSH Connection Error Anyway

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, laravel-5

I'm trying to handle the RunTimeException to connect with VPS through SSH.

Here's the Code to connect with VPS through SSH.

```
$server_ip = Input::get('server_ip');
$password = Input::get('password');

$validator = Validator::make(
    ['server_ip' => $server_ip],
    ['server_ip' => 'ip|required|unique:servers'],
    ['password' => $password],
    ['password' => 'required|confirmed']
);

if(!$validator->fails())
{
    Config::set('remote.connections.production.host',$server_ip);
    Config::set('remote.connections.production.username','root');
    Config::set('remote.connections.production.password',$password);
    Config::set('remote.connections.production.root','/');

    $command = 'mysql --version';

    $connection_status = SSH::run($command, function($line)
    {
        $this->output = $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    if(!$connection_status)
        return $this->output;
    else
        return view('dashboard.add_server');
}
else
    return "Validation failed...";
```

It's Written in Laravel. In case, If I get error with SSH connection, It should redirect me to view named `add_server`. But, I'm getting Exception instead of redirection. Here's the Errror I get every time instead of Redirection.

[image]

What I want is, if there is some error connection to VPS through SSH, it should redirect me to view named **add_server**

Let me know what's wrong with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    $connection_status = SSH::run($command, function($line)
    {
        $this->output = $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    if(!$connection_status)
        return $this->output;
}
catch(\RunTimeException $e)
{
    return view('dashboard.add_server');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `try-catch`

```
try
{
    $connection_status = SSH::run($command, function($line)
    {
        $this->output = $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    if(!$connection_status)
        return $this->output;
}
catch(RunTimeException $e)
{
    return view('dashboard.add_server');
}
```

I don't know if `$connection_status` is supposed to get false value upon successful connection but, apart from that, it should work.